# TYPE CONVERSION: How do you convert a string to a decimal?

Tags: sql, type-conversion, varchar, duckdb

I'm trying to sum a column of `varchar` data, however the values all have commas and decimal points in them. It appears that the query cannot convert a string to a decimal. Help!

I have tried the below query and keep getting the below error message:

```
SELECT SUM(Cast("Repaid to IDA (US$)" as DECIMAL(10,4)))
FROM "banking_table"
WHERE "Country" = 'Bolivia';
```

Error message:

> Conversion Error: Could not convert string "12,063,443.31" to DECIMAL(10,4)

Comment: statement may very from server to server. Which database server are you using?
Additionally, strip comma from your string first.

Comment: using csv fiddle

Comment: how do you strip commas from the string?

Comment: have you checked `REPLACE` method? I do not know if csv fiddle has `REPLACE` method.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: https://csvfiddle.io/about

Comment: It looks like DuckDB - Wasm

Answer (score 0):

I had success with the following statement:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(REPLACE(banking_data."Repaid to IDA (US$)", ',', '') AS DOUBLE)) FROM banking_data;
```

Not sure about this DECIMAL(10, 4) data type. According to the documentation it is unnecessary. And it throws an error when the strings in your table don't match the WIDTH and SCALE properties of it.

Edit: There was a problem with the parathenses in the first example.

As CSVFiddle doesn't allow sharing the whole fiddle including the data, a screenshot has to suffice:

[image]

Comment: I'm still getting an error message with your statement

Comment: Here's the actual dataset if you could upload it to csv fiddle and test it out again

https://finances.worldbank.org/Loans-and-Credits/IDA-Statement-Of-Credits-and-Grants-Historical-Dat/tdwh-3krx/about_data

Comment: See my updated answer. It should work now. I am no expert of duckdb and I would recommend using another DBMS. ;)

Comment: awesome, TY! what DBMS do you recommend? hoping there are better free versions

Comment: I can recommend Microsoft SQL Server or MariaDB / MySQL. There is a free edition available for each of these. It depends on what you want to do in the end.